# RViz segfaults on startup

Tags: ros, rviz, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz crashes in 60% of the startsups with a segfault. I tried the RViz and TF2 versions from debians and from source.
Also I tried with and without a config file.

Seems like the segfaults originates from somewhere out of a dedicated transform listener thread.

Where could I search more deeper for a solution? Any hints are welcome.

Here are two different stacktraces:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd6e5b700 (LWP 13142)]
0x00007ffff459cfc0 in boost::signals2::detail::signal0_impl<void, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::nolock_cleanup_connections_from(bool, std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body<std::pair<boost::signals2::detail::slot_meta_group, boost::optional<int> >, boost::signals2::slot0<void, boost::function<void ()> >, boost::signals2::mutex> > > const&, unsigned int) const () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007ffff459cfc0 in boost::signals2::detail::signal0_impl<void, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::nolock_cleanup_connections_from(bool, std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body<std::pair<boost::signals2::detail::slot_meta_group, boost::optional<int> >, boost::signals2::slot0<void, boost::function<void ()> >, boost::signals2::mutex> > > const&, unsigned int) const () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#1 0x00007ffff459e89b in boost::signals2::detail::signal0_impl<void, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::operator()() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#2 0x00007fffef27efb2 in boost::signals2::signal0<void, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::operator()() (this=0x1f093c0) at /usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp:695
#3 0x00007fffef276776 in tf2::BufferCore::testTransformableRequests (this=0x1f09250)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp:1376
#4 0x00007fffef272d25 in tf2::BufferCore::setTransform (this=0x1f09250, transform_in=..., authority=..., 
is_static=false) at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp:265
#5 0x00007fffef5bbb6b in tf2_ros::TransformListener::subscription_callback_impl (this=0x1f09490, msg_evt=..., 
is_static=false) at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp:119
#6 0x00007fffef5bb95c in tf2_ros::TransformListener::subscription_callback (this=0x1f09490, msg_evt=...)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp:95
#7 0x00007fffef5c41c8 in boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::operator() (this=0x1f099f8, p=0x1f09490, a1=...)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:165
#8 0x00007fffef5c367f in boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&> > (this=0x1f09a08, 
f=..., a=...) at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313
#9 0x00007fffef5c2b2e in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> > >::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> > (this=0x1f099f8, 
a1=...) at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:47
#10 0x00007fffef5c1eaf in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...)
at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#11 0x00007fffef5c4417 in boost::function1<void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> cons
t&>::operator() (this=0x1f099f0, a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:767
#12 0x00007fffef5c3862 in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#13 0x00007fffef5c6274 in boost::function1<void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::operator() (this=0x1f09e18, a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:767
#14 0x00007fffef5c5a70 in ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call (this=0x1f09e10, params=...) at /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:144
#15 0x00007ffff45ee9c5 in ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#16 0x00007ffff45ac777 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) ()
from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#17 0x00007ffff45ad583 in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#18 0x00007fffef5bd1b5 in tf2_ros::TransformListener::dedicatedListenerThread (this=0x1f09490)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/transform_listener.h:80
#19 0x00007fffef5c67e3 in boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>::operator() (this=0x1f0ce48, p=0x1f09490)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:49
#20 0x00007fffef5c6560 in boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list0> (this=0x1f0ce58, f=..., a=...)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:253
#21 0x00007fffef5c5de1 in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> > >::operator() (this=0x1f0ce48)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20
#22 0x00007fffef5c56e6 in boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> > > >::run (this=0x1f0cc90)
at /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117
#23 0x00007ffff5968a4a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
#24 0x00007ffff5747182 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffd6e5b700) at pthread_create.c:312
#25 0x00007ffff62f547d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111



Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd6e5b700 (LWP 24806)]
0x00007fffef28a441 in boost::unordered::detail::table<boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, unsigned int> >, std::string, unsigned int, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string> > >::begin (
this=0x1ff7e98, bucket_index=0) at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:257
257 return prev ? iterator(prev->next_) : iterator();
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007fffef28a441 in boost::unordered::detail::table<boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, unsigned int> >, std::string, unsigned int, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string> > >::begin (
this=0x1ff7e98, bucket_index=0) at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:257
#1 0x00007fffef286600 in boost::unordered::detail::table_impl<boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, unsigned int> >, std::string, unsigned int, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string> > >::find_node_impl<std::string, std::equal_to<std::string> > (this=0x1ff7e98, key_hash=15803753784477690464, k=..., eq=...)
at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:236
#2 0x00007fffef2828a9 in boost::unordered::detail::table<boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, unsigned int> >, std::string, unsigned int, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string> > >::find_node
(this=0x1ff7e98, k=...) at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:782
#3 0x00007fffef27df19 in boost::unordered::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, unsigned int> > >::find (this=0x1ff7e98, k=...)
at /usr/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:1208
#4 0x00007fffef273d03 in tf2::BufferCore::lookupOrInsertFrameNumber (this=0x1ff7e50, frameid_str=...)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp:817
#5 0x00007fffef272b03 in tf2::BufferCore::setTransform (this=0x1ff7e50, transform_in=..., authority=..., 
is_static=false) at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp:249
#6 0x00007fffef5bbb6b in tf2_ros::TransformListener::subscription_callback_impl (this=0x1ff8090, msg_evt=..., 
is_static=false) at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp:119
#7 0x00007fffef5bb95c in tf2_ros::TransformListener::subscription_callback (this=0x1ff8090, msg_evt=...)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp:95
#8 0x00007fffef5c41c8 in boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::operator() (this=0x1ff84c8, p=0x1ff8090, a1=...)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:165
#9 0x00007fffef5c367f in boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&> > (this=0x1ff84d8, 
f=..., a=...) at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313
#10 0x00007fffef5c2b2e in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> > >::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> > (this=0x1ff84c8, 
a1=...) at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:47
#11 0x00007fffef5c1eaf in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener, ros::MessageEvent<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*>, boost::arg<1> > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...)
at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#12 0x00007fffef5c4417 in boost::function1<void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::operator() (this=0x1ff84c0, a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:767
#13 0x00007fffef5c3862 in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#14 0x00007fffef5c6274 in boost::function1<void, boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::operator() (this=0x1ff88e8, a0=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:767
#15 0x00007fffef5c5a70 in ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call (this=0x1ff88e0, params=...) at /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:144
#16 0x00007ffff45ee9c5 in ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#17 0x00007ffff45ac777 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) ()
from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#18 0x00007ffff45ad583 in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#19 0x00007fffef5bd1b5 in tf2_ros::TransformListener::dedicatedListenerThread (this=0x1ff8090)
at /home/iki/rviz_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/transform_listener.h:80
#20 0x00007fffef5c67e3 in boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>::operator() (this=0x1e68048, p=0x1ff8090)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:49
#21 0x00007fffef5c6560 in boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list0> (this=0x1e68058, f=..., a=...)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:253
#22 0x00007fffef5c5de1 in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> > >::operator() (this=0x1e68048)
at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20
#23 0x00007fffef5c56e6 in boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, tf2_ros::TransformListener>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<tf2_ros::TransformListener*> > > >::run (this=0x1e67e90)
at /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117
#24 0x00007ffff5968a4a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
#25 0x00007ffff5747182 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffd6e5b700) at pthread_create.c:312
#26 0x00007ffff62f547d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221028/rviz-segfaults-on-startup/) by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2949 on 2015-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-11-16**:
These tracebacks are very different parts of code, both of which are heavily used by almost every user. As such I would guess that there is something overwriting their memory space. I'd suggest trying out a memory debugging tool to see if they can catch anything.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-11-16**:
Are you running inside of `rqt` or are you using any custom rviz plugins?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-17**:
@william No I run it with `rosrun rviz rviz` and no custom plugins. I deleted the `~/.rviz` folder to eliminate config problems but this didn't help. So our RViz crashes with default config and with our MoveIt! config. Now I'll try the memory tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So we managed to get rid of this problem.
We think that this problem started back when I updated some of the ros core packages (roscpp, roscpp-core, rosmaster and some more).

Today we made a copy of our hard-drive and `sudo apt-get upgrade`ed. Now everything is fine.
Seems like there was an incompatibility between an old and an new package.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-18**:
Yes, it is not really recommended to update only parts of a `deb` based ROS install. The current buildfarm setup does not guarantee binary compatibility between releases, and mix-and-matching pkgs can then result in really difficult to locate/debug issues, such as this `SEGFAULT`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-11-18**:
I'd recommend using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to try and avoid this problem.